# Risk ratio or odds ratio?

Tags: odds-ratio, odds, risk, relative-risk

I have a question which may seem stupid. This is for a retrospective cohort study.

I have a table like this for my outcome:

[image]

Among the 20,000 patients in group A, 4671 are dead (23.55%). Among 50,000 patients in group B, 5755 are dead (11.5%).
I need to calculate the risk ratio for death (group A vs group B)
If I calculated correctly:

- Risk ratio: 2.029
- Odds ratio: 2.342

I did a contingency table like this for the calculation:

[image]

And I did this calculation:

- RISK RATIO = [B2/(B2+C2)] / [B3/(B3+C3)]
- ODDS RATIO = B2* C3 / C2* B3

Our statistician says that the risk ratio is 2.342 (which correspondes to odds ratio according to my calculations). We asked repeatedly to calculate the risk ratio (or relative risk) and he says he calculated the risk ratio as we asked and it is 2.342. I know that the difference between 2.029 and 2342 is slight, however I believe one must report the correct results in the papers…
I wonder if I am calculating it wrong or if maybe there are situations where the risk ratio and odds ratio are interchangeable.

Comment: Your formula and calcluation are correct.  Looks like your statistician made an error. That does happen.